# Which part is emphasised via ‘aber’?

Tags: usage, conjunction

Which part is emphasised with *aber* in the following sentences?

1. > Sie schreibt gern Romane, baut *aber* ungern Betten.

Is it *ungern* or *Betten bauen*, or the entire verbal bracket *ungern Betten bauen*?

2. > Er kommt, *aber* sein Vater ist verhindert.

Is it *sein Vater* or the whole clause *sein Vater ist verhindert*?

Answer (score 1):

*Aber* in these sentences can be seen in exactly the same role that the English word *but* would fill. As such it covers the entire clause

The sentence

> sie schreibt gern Romane, baut *aber* ungern Betten

would translate as

> She loves to write novels *but* she dislikes making beds

The sentence

> er kommt, *aber* sein Vater is verhindert

Aber

> He'll be coming, *but* his father is unable (to come)

Answer (score 0):

The word "aber" always relativises the first part of the sentence (before the comma). So it is related to the first part and does not change the meaning of the words after it.